# Correlation of spark spread

Tags: spread-options

I am following this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.7052&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Deng, Johnson, Sogomonian: *Spark Spread Options and the Valuation of Electricity Generation Assets*, 1999)  to understand spark spread option valuation.

On Page 4, it has `proposition 3` as a closed form solution. However, no where it describes what the formula for `rho (correlation)` should be. Can someone please describe the formula here which will be function of `Fe, Fg, Kh`?

Comment: In equation (1) $\rho$ is defined as the correlation between $dF_e/F_e$ and $dF_g/F_g$. It can be computed from time series data for $F_e$ and $F_g$. Rho is the correlation between returns on Fuel and returns on Electricity.

Comment: It makes sense. I re-read it. Thanks.